# Extremely slow query- Using google sql cloud

Tags: mysql, spring, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way I can speed this up? Right now it's taking an unbelievably insane amount of time to query.

```
SELECT trades.*, trader1.user_name as trader1_name,
trader2.user_name as trader2_name FROM trades
LEFT JOIN logs_players trader1 ON trader1.user_id = trader1_account_id
LEFT JOIN logs_players trader2 ON trader2.user_id = trader2_account_id
ORDER BY time_added
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

I've done as much as I could in terms of searching online for a solution. Or even just trying to get some more information why it's taking so long to execute.

[image]

The query takes about 45 seconds or so to complete.

Create statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `trades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `trader1_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader2_account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader1_value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader2_value` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader1_ip` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader2_ip` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `world` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader1_user` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trader2_user` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE `logs_players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `world_stage` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `world_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank` longtext,
  `inventory` longtext,
  `equipment` longtext,
  `total_wealth` mediumtext,
  `total_play_time` mediumtext,
  `rights` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ironmode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `level` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_online` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `muted_until` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned_until` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Show your create statements on trades, and logs_players please.

Comment: @FrankerZ edited the post with it. Thanks for the reply man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled a sample database with 10k rows each, and found that a few indexes were what you needed:

```
ALTER TABLE `logs_players` ADD INDEX(`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `trades` ADD INDEX(`time_added`);
```

The main index we need is an index on `user_id`. Changing that we went from a query time of 20.1390 seconds, to [0.0130](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Fwi.png) seconds:

[image]

We can even get that down further, by adding an index on time_added to make sorting a lot faster, now we ended up with an impressive query time:

[image]

Do some research on indexes! A simple EXPLAIN query would show you that you're using filesort (Which is rather bad!):
[image]

After indexes, this looks a lot better:
[image]

Comment: Dude you're a legend. Thanks so much for the help. Gonna implement this now.

Comment: @user9097072 If you're into making this the best possible, I highly recommend looking into foreign key indexes, which ensure data integrity when rows get deleted or updated.